# Programmatically identify when a new instance of a microservice has been created or killed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is there a way to programmatically identify if the number of instances of a single microservices has reached a certain number at a given time?
For instance: how can I know programmatically how many instances of my Account microservices there are running right now? Also, how to find out when that number changed?

My intention is to notify an admin when it goes over a threshold. I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Cloud, Spring Config and Consul as service discovery. I would be willing to change to Eureka if needed.

Comment: Service discovery can provide information about what you want, do you want to know information about on other microservice, right?

Comment: Yes, in another application actually, most probably a scheduled job. But Ideally I would like to implement a listener, that listens when the number of instances changes, could that be done?

Comment: yes, you can get it, let me add code as answer..

Comment: but I am not sure if it is the same for Consul ... :V

Comment: I'd use the `ConsulClient` to watch services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based documentation you can use [DiscoveryClient](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.2.3.RELEASE/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-discovery.html#_using_the_discoveryclient) in order to get instances based on some service on the documentation example is `"STORES"`, take a look, you can do it by following example:

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

public List<ServiceInstance> getInstances(String serviceName) {
    List<ServiceInstance> list = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceName);
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0 ) {
        // logic here if it is necessary. 
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to listen for event